# Does a symbolic disassembler exist?

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I would like to know if there are disassemblers based on a symbolic analysis, I'm beginner in RE, but I think that a disassembler based on symbolic techniques can be very interesting and could disassemble most of the obfuscated binaries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, most of the disassembler based on '*symbolic execution*' are kind of symbolic. The problem is that you need to modelize so much from the environment (system calls answers, interaction with other programs, ...) that most of them also use concrete execution when the program venture outside of their model.

But, you should look for [symbolic execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution) tools such as [angr](https://angr.io/), [miasm](https://miasm.re/blog/) and many others.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I'm looking them !